# html5 audio: changing currentTime fires multiple canplay events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I need to change the offset time for an HTML5 audio element. I've written a function which handles the **canplay** event and changes the currentTime attribute.

However, it seems that changing the currentTime attribute fires the event and so it goes on in a loop. When I comment out the currentTime changing, it works normally (i. e. the event only fires once).

What is the proper way to do it? This behaviour occurs in (at least) Firefox and Chrome. As a result, the music does not play normally

```
<audio id="current" src="http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02.wav" controls 
start="1000" end="2000">    
</audio>
<script>

 $('audio').bind('canplay', function(event) {
     alert("fire!");
    event.target.currentTime = 0.5;
 });
 </script>
```

[can check it on jsfiddle, too](https://jsfiddle.net/6qchtbdj/3/)

Actually, it seems to work with the **loadedmetadata** event but everyone suggests canplay is better and compatible with more browsers

Comment: you can change the `.bind` to `.one` - that way it will fire only once.

Comment: @naortor thank you very much! It works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use .one instead of .bind in order to listen to it only on the first time

```
$('audio').one('canplay', function(event) {
    console.log("fire!");
    event.target.currentTime = 0.5;
});
```